# SQL Optimizing the Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following query,

```
SELECT qTermine.REISENR, 
       qTermine.REISEVON, 
       qTermine.REISEBIS, 
       MIN(qPreise.PREIS) AS PREIS 
FROM   qTermine, 
       qPreise 
WHERE  qPreise.REISENR = qTermine.REISENR 
       AND qPreise.PROVKLASSE = 1 
       AND qPreise.VERFUEGBAR <> 0 
GROUP  BY qTermine.REISENR, 
          qTermine.REISEVON, 
          qTermine.REISEBIS
```

I only want to select those rows where the Price is minimum.

Is it OK or we can optimize it?

Comment: I hope you don't use this to decide where to go on vacation. Seriously, it looks ok. You could also write it as a non-aggregated subquery. You would have to test to see which is faster. Maybe look at plans with relevant data.

Comment: I think it is ok from the point of view of optimization. But I cannot understand why you use `AS PREIS` part. As I see you never use that designation in your code.

Comment: @Karen: Since it's in the `SELECT` clause, that'll be the name of that field as it is being output to the client executing the query, which may well reference it by that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query itself is good as it is. It's hard to come at this question, as for most uses, what you've written is fine. Are you currently experiencing performance issues, or is this query being executed extreme amounts of time? Or are you just cautious and want to avoid introducing a big bottleneck? In case of the latter, I don't think you need to be worried; again, in most uses, that's fine.

Make sure you have an index on `REISENR` on both tables and on `qPreise.PREIS`. As for `PROVKLASSE` and `VERFUEGBAR` I have a feeling that they won't be unique enough for indexes to actually ever be used if you were to add them (you could check that in your execution plan), but it's hard to tell without intimately knowing your data.

Answer (score 0):

You query is good and You can have a better performance if you have index on "qPreise.PREIS"